# matplotlib radar plot min values

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

I started with the matplotlib radar example but values below some min values disappear.
I have a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/dschien/8805271).

The result looks like

[image: this]

As you can see in the gist, the values for D and E in series A are both 3 but they don't show up at all.

There is some scaling going on. 
In order to find out what the problem is I started with the original values and removed one by one.

When I removed one whole series then the scale would shrink.
Here an example (removing Factor 5) and scale in [0,0.2] range shrinks.

From

[image: this]

to

[image: series]

I don't care so much about the scaling but I would like my values at 3 score to show up.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the values for D and E in series A do show up, although they are plotted in the center of the plot. This is because the limits of your "y-axis" is autoscaled.

If you want to have a fixed "minimum radius", you can simply put `ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)` in your `for`-loop.

If you want the minimum radius to be a number relative to the lowest plotted value, you can include something like `ax.set_ylim(np.asarray(data.values()).flatten().min() - margin)` in the `for`-loop, where `margin` is the distance from the lowest plotted value to the center of the plot.

With fixed center at radius 0 (added markers to better show that the points are plotted):

[image]

By setting `margin = 1`, and using the relative y-limits, I get this output:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer! Thank you very much.